# retrieve Date and time filed value from one list and assign it to another list field "share point online"

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-designer, javascript

so far i have retrieved the values and assigned them from "List A" to "List B" with same column names, 
1) but date and time column called "End date and Time" needs to be split in to date and time separately and assign it to filed in "List B", right now able to get the value like this using REST API .[image: which is coming like this] but i need to separate the date and time in to this [image].

2) and i need to compare the date and time filed("End date and Time") above with current date and time before submitting the form, basically it will decide whether it is a on-time submission or late submission, it should not create the item if it is a late submission instead it should redirect to a page.

Please any help.